# Removing Google Analytics cookie string from URL - security hole?

Tags: javascript, xss

On our site, we use google analytics and we have to put the GA cookie in the URL since we have a two letter domain and IE imposes some cookie limitations on those. This means that when going between subdomains we get these long URLs with the cookie string appended after a hash:

```
http://test.ab.la#_utma=what_have_you&_utmc=something_else&so=on&so=on
```

So, I added this code:

```
(* Remove fragment (the part after #) from URL if it contains a Google Analytics cookie.
   We do this to hide the extremely long URLs that otherwise will be visible to the users.
   Will not work in IE and other browsers that do not support history.replaceState().
   Use GA's push functionality to do this to make sure the page has been tracked before
   removing cookie information.*)
_gaq.push(function() {
    if (window.history &&
        window.history.replaceState &&
        location.href.indexOf("__utma") > 0) {
        window.history.replaceState({}, "", document.location.href.split("#")[0]);
    }
});
```

After watching [a talk at Jfokus](http://www.slideshare.net/johnwilander/application-security-for-rich-internet-applicationss-jfokus-2012) by [John Wilander](https://twitter.com/johnwilander) where he mentioned [a specific Twitter security issue](http://blog.mindedsecurity.com/2010/09/twitter-domxss-wrong-fix-and-something.html), I got a little nervous.

My question is: **Would my little hack above introduce any security holes, XSS or others?** I don't **think** so, but I guess you've heard that before.

**Update:**

Maybe I should clarify my maybe somewhat unclear question: I did suspect that I wasn't having the exact same security problem as the Twitter one, but I since I am doing similar things I am wondering if there are any **other** vulnerabilities in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Twitter hole was that they didn't check that the URI supplied in the fragment identifier was what they expected it to be (a root-relative path). It could be any other URI, including an external site, or (what caused the XSS), a non-locating-URI (ah, `javascript:` URIs—how we all wish you had never been invented).

You don't have this hole here because (a) you are re-using the scheme and hostname from the existing document URI, which must necessarily be a locating-URI, and (b) you are using `replaceState`: this only updates the apparent path showing in the address bar, and does not actually navigate to the target address.

You could use `location.path+location.search` as an alternative way of getting the rooted-path part without bothering with splitting out the other parts manually.

How you are handling re-injecting the cookies, and whether you care about the analytics cookies being easily falsified/leaked, might have other implications.

Comment: Thanks! Please see the small update at then end of my question.

Comment: Well, there's not really much you can do with `replaceState` that's a vulnerability in itself. And there's not inherently a problem with repopulating analytics cookies, as long as you set them in a safe way, avoiding writing any other cookies you might want to protect, and you don't care about analytics session tokens being spoofable. Can't guarantee that without more code and context though.

Answer (score 1):

In the linked example there is the following problem: Twitter tried to detect anything after the hashbang and add it to the URL proper. They did it the following way:

```
a = location.href.split("#!")[1]
window.location = a
```

In theory the browser will now set the URL to everything behind the hashbang. So if the url was `twitter.com/#!/user/someone` it would set the URL to `twitter.com/user/someone` (basically append `/user/someone` to `twitter.com`, since the browser realizes there is no protocol/hostname given). The problem with this approach is, that if the URL is `twitter.com/#!javascript:alert('Hello World')` the browser will try to interpret the javascript code (since the browser doesn't append it now to twitter.com, but instead sets `window.location` to `javscript:alert('Hello World')`). It will identify javascript: as the protocol, and so try to execute everything after it according to that protocol definition.

They solved in this way:

```
a = location.href.split("#!")[1]
window.location.hash = ""
window.location.pathname = a
```

Instead of setting the `window.location` directly (which is dangerous as shown above) they now just set the hash of the location (everything after `#`) to an empty string and set the path on the pathname property, which doesn't execute the javascript code. Why? The `window.location` property allows the protocol to change (for example from `http` to `javascript` if so defined).

So in your case you should be fine (at least this attack won't work). Why? You just strip everything **after** the first `#` (also adding two # won't help, since it will be split on the first `#`). So the string set to `window.location` will always start with the current protocol and your host, and never with `javascript:`, so the browser will never try to execute anything.

Comment: Thanks! Please see the small update at then end of my question.

Comment: I don't think you introduce a new vulnerability here. Twitter had the problem because they took the part after the hash, so the browser could be tricked to execute javascript. Since you take the part before the hash, an attacker can't trick a browser into executing javascript on the page.